# django-excel pyexcel show unknown parameters for django heroku

Tags: python, django, excel, heroku, pyexcel

My django app deployed in heroku managed to show upload file form. However once I try uploading Excel xlsx file, it shows

```
UnknownParameters at /
Please check if there were typos in function parameters: {'model': None, 'initializer': None, 'mapdict': None}. 
Otherwise unrecognized parameters were given.
```

Following installation setup has done for django-excel

**requirements.txt**

```
pyinstaller
django-excel
pyexcel-xls
pyexcel-xlsx
pyexcel-ods
```

I am sure that my **models.py** is connected and along with the mapdict parameters matches correctly

I've seen similar issue [Why pyexcel throws exception "UnknownParameters: Please check if there were typos in function parameters"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608780/why-pyexcel-throws-exception-unknownparameters-please-check-if-there-were-typo) and I tried installing pyinstaller along with hidden imports

```
--hidden-import pyexcel_xls
--hidden-import pyexcel_xls.xlsr
--hidden-import pyexcel_xls.xlsw
```

but unfortunately it still doesn't work for my app

I wonder if there is any clue to solve this for me to run my django web application on heroku? or any advice or learning for hidden-import to run within heroku web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend hosting your django app in pythonanywhere.com

With a little bit of search I found that people is having problem with the library you are using for excel files when deploying in heroku, maybe heroku can't support pyexcel.

Here is a tutorial of how to deploy your app in pythonanywhere https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4c4ickks2A

Comment: Woaw! That sounds so amazing! I will give it a try in a bit, once I starting my digging in journey again! Thank you so much for the light path! Will post you again once I have done tested it!

Comment: alright, if you have any problem when hosting it on pythonanywhere tell me, I have experience with that, also if it works, don't forget to put this as the correct answer, have a great day

Comment: Surely do, so helpful of you! Will keep you updated when there's any new status on my question!